# Laravel Many To Many Save

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have tag and post models.

**Migration Tag**

```
class CreateTagsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamp();
        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('tags');
        schema::drop('post_tag');
    }
}
```

**Migration Post**

```
class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->text('filename');
            $table->timestamps();

    });
}

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
         Schema::drop('posts');
    }
}
```

**App\Tag**

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $table="tags";
    public $timestamps = true;


    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     * Many to Many relations make with post
     */
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post','post_tag','post_id');
    }
}
```

**App\Post**

```
class Post extends Model
{

    protected $table="posts";
    public $timestamps = true;


    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'filename'];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     * one to many relationship with user
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return BelongsToMany relationship with tags
     * 
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag','post_tag','tag_id')->withTimestamps();

    }


}
```

I want to attach posts and tags.There is create post form and ı want to this form attach tags. How will do I?

**PostController@store**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    \Auth::user()->posts()->save(new Post($request->all()));
    return \Redirect::route('posts.index');
}
```

I found in Laravel Documentation but i dont use method

```
App\User::find(1)->roles()->save($role, ['expires' => $expires]);
```

Comment: This is a little confusing, could you clarify further?  You show your `Post` and `Tag` models but then it looks like you are attaching a `Post` to your `User` and then attaching a `Role` to your `User`.  It's unclear what you are asking exactly.

Comment: You're right. I edit this question

Comment: I have edited. I want to attach post and tag

Comment: You should be using attach for many to many relationships I believe. Check out the docs for further info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 1):

Use the sync method:

```
App\User::find(1)->roles()->sync($roles);
```

When $roles is an array of roles ids:

```
$roles = [
    0 => '1', // role_id 1
    1 => '2', // role_id 2
    2 => '5', // role_id 5
];
```

Search for **Syncing For Convenience** at the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships